# Where is SignalR 0.5.3?

Tags: nuget, signalr

On multiple sources in internet i see that SignalR 0.5.3 is released, i even find the screenshot of NuGet Manager which has v 0.5.3 on it. [image]

But in my Nuget manages there is only v 0.5.2 and [here](http://nuget.org/packages/signalr) also latest is 0.5.2.

So, the question is where do i get the latest SignalR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like 0.5.3 is on the gallery, just hasn't been tagged as the newest release.

http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR/0.5.3

Try running this in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package SignalR -Version 0.5.3
```

However, I suspect that 0.5.3 has been pulled because of a problem (?) since the official [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) web site says 0.5.2 is the latest. It might also be that they are going to rename the NuGet package to `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`.

Comment: SignalR currently has a pre-release of 1.0alpha2 on the gallery.  Just search Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR and set your filter to allow for pre-release.

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen thanks I thought it might have been a prerelease package, but interestingly the screenshot above shows "Stable Only" selected.